# Positive Feedback in Time Domain

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator

[image]

Let us consider the circuit above (R3 and R4 should actually be \$1\$ ohm each)

Using time-domain analysis, we reach that \$V_o=-6V_2\$.

Using laplace transforms (Block Diagrams), we would just have a negative transfer function.

What I cannot understand is this:

1) Intuitively, this system must oscillate since we are making a signal greater by a constant factor, returning it back, then multiplying again, so where did I go wrong in calculations?

2) Can we reach that this system oscillates algebraically without any intuition whatsoever?

Comment: "*R3 and R4 should actually be 1 ohm each*", then update your schematic.

Comment: I don't think it would matter much (if we had an ideal op-amp) to be honest since I'd still have the same \$A\$ and \$\beta\$ which is my point. It's just that I used 1 ohms while simulating

Comment: When you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar the editable schematic gets saved inline in your post. This avoids the need to take a screengrab (with the grid in it) and is editable so your component errors can be fixed. Double-click a component to edit its properties. "*It's just that I used 1 ohms while simulating.*" If the simulator is in any way realistic it won't work with such a low impedance load.

Comment: Even if it weren't realistic, I'm concerned with the understanding of the ideal case. Also, thanks for the tip on the editor toolbar

Comment: By "ideal case" do you mean "infinite voltage range at the output" and "infinite gain?"

Comment: Yes, and that no current enters the OP-AMP inputs etc.

Comment: I provided some kind of answer that I hope makes sense (to you and to me, alike.)

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible states. In both cases, \$V_2\$ is irrelevant since it is finite.

1. If \$V_O=+\infty\$ then \$V_2\$, being finite, can be ignored. \$V_+=\frac{+\infty}{2}\$ and \$V_-=\frac{+\infty}{3}\$. Since \$V_+\gt V_-\$, the opamp holds \$V_O=+\infty\$.
2. If \$V_O=-\infty\$ then \$V_2\$, being finite, can be ignored. \$V_+=\frac{-\infty}{2}\$ and \$V_-=\frac{-\infty}{3}\$. Since \$V_+\lt V_-\$, the opamp holds \$V_O=-\infty\$.

The above follows because:

$$\begin{align*}
V_+&=\frac{V_O}{2}+V_2\\\\
V_-&=\frac{V_O}{3}
\end{align*}$$

It's a binary state that depends on the initial condition of the output.

---

If you limit the output to a pair of voltage rails you provide, \$V_\text{CC}\$ and \$V_\text{EE}\$, then the situation is different. You have a range of hysteresis. Starting \$V_2\$ from well below \$\frac{-V_\text{CC}}{6}\$, and raising it upwards, the output will transition from \$V_\text{EE}\$ to \$V_\text{CC}\$ at \$V_2=\frac{-V_\text{EE}}{6}\$. Starting \$V_2\$ from well above \$\frac{-V_\text{EE}}{6}\$, and lowering it downwards, the output will transition from \$V_\text{CC}\$ to \$V_\text{EE}\$ at \$V_2=\frac{-V_\text{CC}}{6}\$.

In the somewhat more realistic case where also the open loop gain is large, but finite, then there will be a very tiny linear transition slope nearby the above-mentioned transition points. (And assuming an even more realistic opamp with BJT inputs, there will be substantial input loading for the input nodes when the voltages at the nodes are more than a few tens of millivolts apart from each other, since the differential amplifier inputs only present a tiny load in the case where the inputs are very close to each other in voltage.)

Comment: How did you actually conclude that \$V_o\$ is infinite in the first place? I mean, we know it oscillates, but it doesn't appear here.

The only explanation I could reach is that this circuit is not realistic since we just assumed that there is no delay in the paths and that somehow this system will become stable (so we could use Kirchoff's equations)
I suppose with delay, it will appear to oscillate. Otherwise, nothing makes sense.

Comment: @HasanSaad I started out with ideal amplifiers which means their outputs are unbounded. I thought that approach might help. Obviously, it didn't help you at all. But I also dealt with the case where they have finite limits to their output.

Comment: I understand your point, but due to the application of feedback on the inverting part of the ideal op-amp (with infinite gain \$A\$), the gain would become finite as is obvious by applying the finite model then taking limits.

What I mean is, why would there be any oscillation at all? Where did I go wrong in my derivation from Kirchoff's law?

Comment: @HasanSaad I don't know what you mean by the term, "oscillation." I think there is a language barrier. It doesn't oscillate, so far as I know. So you must be using it in a way I haven't experienced.

Comment: It doesnt? Doesnt this work in the same principle as the Wein Bridge Oscillator except that there isnt any resonant frequency?

Comment: @HasanSaad I didn't see a Wein Bridge oscillator mentioned. So this is new to me. In any case, the circuit you provided doesn't oscillate.

Comment: Well, I dont know whats the difference between the usual oscillators that use positive feedback and this but thanks anyway. I appreciate your efforts

Comment: @HasanSaad The other problem with real opamps in a circuit like this is that the inputs must be very close to each other (within a few dozens of mV) or else the inputs will sink/source LOTS of current. So any real design will have to account for that. An ideal amplifier doesn't care -- the inputs never sink/source. But in the case of a real one, the only predictable operation is when the inputs are very close to each other.

Comment: Yeah mate, but I'm just working theory here.

Comment: @HasanSaad Then the \$\infty\$ applies, assuming you permit no limit on the output. Show me why the gain is finite. I didn't see you calculate any such thing, so I don't know what you are talking about. An ideal opamp has infinite open loop voltage gain. Not finite. Assume V2=0. What do you expect at the output of the opamp?